# Easing the excution flow in JS/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Easing the excution flow in JS/JQuery
I've loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{ 
   doSomething(...); // returns momentally
}
```

I'm looking for a way to apply easing to the execution flow - by giving a total duration and an easing pattern (ex. 2 seconds & easeback). Is is something doable in JS (I'm using jQuery too)?

---

**Update 2** Updated to clarify the question - I'm looking for the following:

**Update 3** - Sheikh Heera is right, the sample I gave doesn't illustrate the real problem, execute function is updated to call an external module, which is closer to what I have. I don't see how jQuery's animate can be applied directly for calling functions.

```
easer.ease({ start: 0, 
   end: 100, 
   duration: 900, 
   easing: "easeOutBounce",
   execute: function (e) { ExternalModule.DoSomethingUseful(e); } });
```

where `start` the `end` are integers, specifying the animated range, `duration` is animation duration in milliseconds, `easing` is the easing pattern used to animate the values within a range, `execute` - the function which gets called with values from `0` to `100`, using the easing pattern supplied in the sample above it will animate myDiv's height from `0` to `100` within `0.9` seconds using `easeOutBounce` easing function.

Ideally as a small standalone plugin based on `jQuery`, definitely not part of `Mootools` or any other heavy hitters I can't afford bringing them in just for that.

Comment: what is your goal using this? animation?

Comment: You really need to be more specific and help us get a picture of what are you trying to do here.

Comment: There's no need to reinvent the wheel, `jQuery's` `animate` method is made for this.

Comment: @Sheikh Heera there certainly isn't, but how do I apply it to my problem???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my best, I tried to achieve the thing you want using jQuery "animate" property.

Using this jQuery property will allow to add "easing", "duration", "callback" etc as needed by you. I used the "step" property to achieve this.

In order to work, you need to add a "dummy" tag to the HTML and hide it.

### DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/vaakash/Wtqm3/

**HTML**

```
<!-- Add a dummy tag to apply animate property -->
<span class="holder" style="display:none" ></span>​
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.holder').animate(
    {
        'end': 100 // There is no such "end" css property just using as an end mark
    },
    {
        duration: 500,
        step: function(now, fx) {
            myFunction(now); // Call your function here with the "now" param (i.e ExternalModule.DoSomethingUseful(now) ) in your case                      
        }
        // Add easing property if wanted
    }
);

// The function
function myFunction(param){
    $('body').append('Value now: ' + param + '</br/>');
}​
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly....You could try using .delay(100) or .delay(xmilliseconds) so it takes longer at each step.

Read more about delay on : http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: delay is at a too low level, I'm looking for a wrapper which would take the number of calls, total time and easing pattern and do it for me... just wasn't sure if it's been done already

Answer (score 1):

### Easing in jQuery

jQuery only has two easings, linear and swing. What you are looking for is the functions used in the jQuery UI. They can be accessed from `$.easing`.

[**$.easing demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sinetheta/R3NRC/) where you can play with them.

You can call any function you'd like by name `$.easing.easeOutBounce(e, t, n, r)`. The only confusing part is that they are actually 4 variable functions. From the jQuery UI docs:

> based on [easing equations](http://www.robertpenner.com/easing) from Robert Penner

The "standard" way to use them in `f(x, 0, 0, 1)` since `e` is the variable we typically want to change. `n` seems to be a "start point" for most functions, `t` looks to be a "power" in many of them, and `r` a linear scale factor.

#### Disclaimer

This is only my best guess from looking at the jquery and jquery-ui source files. I'd recommend if you want to do easing that you just write your own functions instead of relying on internal parts that are certainly not part of the stable API.

### Your ease function

Although I wouldn't recommend making a function like this, it *was* an interesting experiment. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sinetheta/LBPMG/).

```
var ease = function(options) {
    var t = 0;
    // we need a time interval for animating
    var tstep = options.interval || 10;
    var duration = options.duration || 500
    var i = options.start || 0;
    var end = options.end || 100;
    // the easing functions only work over x=0..1
    var scale = end - i;
    //  one divided by the number of tsteps
    var interval = tstep/duration;
    var easing = options.easing || 'linear';
    var callback = options.execute || function(){}; 
    var timeout = function() {
        // we call the callback but pass it the scale result of our easing
        callback(scale*$.easing[easing](Math.min(i, 1)));
        // if we haven't reached the end of the animation, queue up another frame
        if (t <= duration) {
            window.setTimeout(function() {       
                 timeout();
            }, tstep);
            i += interval;
            t += tstep;
        }
    };
    timeout();
};

ease({
    start: 0,
    end: 100,
    duration: 900,
    easing: 'easeOutBounce',
    // we'll print to the screen the results of the easing
    execute: function(e) {$('body').append('<p>' + e)}
});
```